# Is it possible to make dynamic posts to Facebook's opengraph from the same page in an app?

Tags: vb.net, facebook-graph-api

I've been reading and working on making a Facebook app over the last little while. From what I see, I need a separate page for each different type of object I'm posting about. This is great for simple HTML pages, but when developing applications, it creates a massive overhead. Is there any way to make a post of different types from the same dynamically created page?

Example: There is a shopping mall page. Say the user buys lettuce, we create a dynamic page to inform them of their purchase. The user later comes back and buys an apple. We then create the same page to inform them of their purchase, but this time it is about an apple.

How would I go about posting they purchased lettuce, and they purchased an apple from the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I see, I need a separate page for each different type of object I'm posting about.

Yes. Every Open Graph object is represented by its individual URL.

> This is great for simple HTML pages, but when developing applications, it creates a massive overhead.

Not really – URL parameters exist, and make it easy to “create” OG objects on-the-fly by just outputting content according to GET parameters.

> Example: There is a shopping mall page. Say the user buys lettuce, we create a dynamic page to inform them of their purchase. The user later comes back and buys an apple. We then create the same page to inform them of their purchase, but this time it is about an apple.

So the lettuce and the apple are two different Open Graph objects, and the user interacts with both of them at different points in time. So there is neither a *need* to try to “combine” them into one object, nor a good reason.

> How would I go about posting they purchased lettuce, and they purchased an apple from the same page?

By first publishing an instance of your “buy” action for the object “lettuce”, and then publishing another instance for the object “apple” afterwards.

Comment: I'm a little confused, your answer seems very vague.


From what I've read, you don't actually post, but instead generate a request for Facebook to go and generate an OG post, from a page you've created, which has been scraped. I still don't see a way around creating all those pages. It would be great if you could actually just pass the parameters a create a post yourself, even if you have to create seperate objects for everything on Facebook's end. Am I missing something?

Comment: RE: So there is neither a need to try to “combine” them into one object, nor a good reason.

This concept is "categories", and is a requirement for living a normal day to day life. In my example, the two objects are of the same category "produce". It seems really foolish to say there is no good reasons for categories to exist.

Comment: If “produce” is your object, you still have different versions of it – because lettuce is not an apple. So you could store that info (lettuce or apple) in your own object properties – but you will still need to different URLs for lettuce and for apple. And about the dynamic “creation” of such objects, I don’t see your problem – f.e. GET parameters make that really simple.

Comment: I'm talking about creating pages dynamically via .NET. My problem is "you will still need to different URLs" Thanks for the confirmation it can't be done though. :(

Comment: URLs with different GET parameters resp. a different query string __are__ different URLs.